# Why JS objects with numeric keys cannot be accessed with dot notation

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

So I'm learning Arrays in JS (ES6), And I wondered why can't we access array elements with dot notation

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr[0]); //fine
console.log(arr['0']); //it works, some internal typecasting I guess
console.log(arr.0); // fails
console.log(arr.'0'); // fails too.
```

As JS philosophy says (not an official statement though) :

> "Everything in JS is an Object"

Following that I expected it to work here, but then I tried implementing my own array using object. (don't know how it is actually implementation).

```
var obj = {0:1, 1:2, 2:3, 3:4, 4:5};
console.log(obj[0]); //works 
console.log(obj['0']); //works
console.log(obj.0); //fails 
console.log(obj.'0'); //fails
```

So even my own implementation, gives the same results as actual array implementation.

```
var obj = {"012":0, "a012":1};
console.log(obj.012); //fails
console.log(obj."012"); //fails
console.log(obj[012]); //surprisingly fails returns undefined.
console.log(obj["012"]); //works
console.log(obj.a012); //It works ah .
```

What's wrong in accessing objects with numeric keys using dot notation?
I know the fact property should be a string, but "012" or any other string just containing numerical letters (no alphabets) is not valid. Why?

Comment: Property names must be strings. This means that non-string objects cannot be used as keys in the object. Any non-string object, including a number, is typecasted into a string via the toString method. ... but this seems to be only half of the problem :)

Comment: ...and this expailns why `...[012]` returns `undefined` - since it's searching actually for `'12'` key and did not found that

Comment: In array the "index" means the memory offset from the start of the array, there is no mapping to object as it would involve extra overhead...

Comment: @skyboyer nope, it is searching for "10"

Comment: as for `.<any number here>` just deal with it. I suppose it have been done to make parsing code easier: dot + numbers after means fractional part of numbers, dot + alphanumeric means accessing property

Comment: @Kaiido yes, you are right. It's a number to be in octal system

Comment: Also, numbers starting with zero are treated as octal numbers... eg 012 is cast to 012+"" == "10"

Comment: @AlekseiMaide thanks for explaining it, I have one more thing to ask why any key which is a string with only numerical characters cannot be accessed using dot notation?

Comment: I guess the interpreter doesn't know how to parse it... must be ambigous... var obj = {"12":0}; typeof Object.keys(obj)[0]; //string... and obj.hasOwnProperty(12) //true ... the property clearly exists, my guess is it's simply a syntax limitation...

Comment: @AlekseiMaide kinda make sense.

Comment: @AnkitKumarOjha: It's pretty simply really: To use dot notation, the property name must be a valid **identifier** (i.e. something like a valid variable name (but also including keywords)). Numbers are not valid identifiers.

Comment: @FelixKling If it is so, You have cleared all my doubts. Can you please share the sources for the comment you have written.

Comment: Here is the spec: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-property-accessors. Note that the production rule is `MemberExpression . IdentifierName`. If you click on `IdentifierName` you can see its rules.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks a lot.